# Is this the correct way to say "child of the octopus"?

Tags: translation, usage, particles

I'm still very new to Japanese, but I've learned that octopus is たこ and child is 子. In addition to this, I'm aware that the の particle is used to show possession; for example:

> わたし の なまえ ...

Here, it's my understanding that the の particle is demonstrating possession of なまえ by わたし, effectively saying "my name is". With this understanding, one could arrive at the conclusion that たこの子 would translate to "child of the octopus", roughly.

---

Is this the correct way to say "child of the octopus"?

Comment: Note that this phrase, _tako no ko_, also refers to octopus roe as a food item.  [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%90%22&tbm=isch) for [タコの子]{tako no ko} shows many dishes made from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ...that ...is ...correct.

Comment: (I don't usually write like that, but SE doesn't allow answers consisting of fewer than 30 characters...)